# Website video behaviour issues with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, safari

I have a website which has a button which which clicked, the video launcher slides up and plays a video. This seems to be working in all browsers apart from Safari. When I go to the websites url on Safari, for some reason, the video is already launched but not playing. Any ideas how to make this behave like other browsers

Here is the [Url](http://www.instituteofrobotics.co.uk/staging/index.html)

Comment: Please paste in code that you need assistance with.  A URL like this will not be useful to anyone in the future since, no doubt, the page will be fixed or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Safari has some problems with the video tag try this:

https://html5media.info/

This allows you to show videos in all browsers.